# What is this hardy plant with purple flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant, originating from a flower seed mix, is the only survivor of the central European winter on my balcony.

- The flowers have a mild scent of roses
- Other plants in the package that I could identify are cornflower ([*Centaurea cyanus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurea_cyanus)) and bell flower ([*Campanula medium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campanula_medium))
- The plant in the picture has been exposed to temperatures ranging between -5°C and +35°C

What is it?

[image]

Comment: The flower looks a bit like a Streptocarpus, but I the leaf is wrong, more investigating required

Comment: Welcome to the site Glo! I have a couple of questions, if you don't mind. What were some of the other plants in the package? Is your balcony in the sun or shade most of the time? Do the flowers have any scent? What's the general range of temperatures where you live? You can just [edit] those, and any other details that might be helpful, right into your question. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider [registering](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) your accounts, then you can [merge them](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 5):

It is [Orychophragmus violaceus](http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Orychophragmus%20violaceus).

This relative of mustard is biennial, native to east Asia and it has edible flowers. In Europe the plant is rather rare I believe.

Comment: You might want to add a link and a bit more info regarding the plant, Lorgim

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. As Bamboo said, we like our answers to have more info, so the people who read it can learn from you. Sometimes answers like this can be deleted, and I don't want that to happen to you! Press the gray word that says "edit" or press this [edit] to add more details.  If you have any problems, leave a comment and someone will help you. Our [help] explains how our site works. Check out the [answer] page. We hope you'll have fun here!

Comment: Thank you was intrigued to know. It's grown for its leaves and used in Chinese cooking

Comment: Hi Lorgim! You were unable to edit your original question because you have a couple of **unregistered** user accounts. Please consider [registering](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) one of them, then you can [merge them](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), and [comment on](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!